# CakePHP 3.x use Plugin in a Plugin

Tags: cakephp, filter

Trying to use the Search Plugin from friendsofcake in my cakedc users plugin.

I used everthing like before (in my normal users/index.ctp it worked) and just added my custom index.ctp to the cakedc users controller, like so:

```
public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Search.Prg', [
            'actions' => ['index']
        ]);
    }
public function index()
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('backend');

    $query = $this->Users
        // Use the plugins 'search' custom finder and pass in the
        // processed query params
        ->find('search', $this->Users->filterParams($this->request->query))
        // You can add extra things to the query if you need to
        ->contain(['Skills'])
        ->where(['firstname IS NOT' => null]);

    $this->set('users', $this->paginate($query));
}
```

But I am getting the error

> Unknown method "filterParams"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filterParams()` *was* a method of the CakeDC search plugin. It's not available in the FoC plugin nor it still is in the CDC plugin. The FoC Search is not a drop in replacement but a completely different implementation. I've worked on both and I prefer FoC search because the code was written for Cake3 and is IMHO better than the other implementation that was "just" an upgrade from the Cake2 implementation.

I don't know from where you got filterParams() any way. I couldn't find it in the latest CDC docs nor the code. You might want to report it as a bug.